# Flutter Web - screen/lock screen state detection from the PC browser

Tags: flutter, browser

My goal is to logout the user from a flutter web application if the PC goes to sleep or if the user locks the PC.

Is there an Flutter API/Plugin to detect if the PC screen has gone to sleep or if the PC has been blocked or in general if the modern PC browsers has this ability to detect these screen PC states?

I know that the most popular solution is to use a timer, but I wanted to understand if there was an ad hock solution for this case.

Comment: I don't think there's a nice solution for this. We wanted something similar but ended up making the project also compatible as flutter desktop app along with having the flutter web app to be able to have this functionality. But I would love to hear if there's actually a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

As you use Flutter web, you can rely on javascript API.

Some browser provide an experimental API to detect froze/resume events: https://whatwebcando.today/freeze-resume.html

But be carefull as it's experimental, not all browser implement it. Please see https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_document_freeze_event to verify it suit your needs.